# How to specify a class property from a string in java

Tags: java, csv, filtering, java.util.scanner

So I am reading from a file with scanner it has the similar format:

```
title, name, age
Mr, Matthew, 20
mr,  Paul, 30
miss, Anne, 24
```

CSV^

```
class person{
String name, title;
int age; 

public  crimeData(String csv){
    String[]list = csv.split(",", -1);
    name = list[0];
    title = list[1];
    age = list[2];
}
}
```

Console Program

```
    Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);

    System.out.println("Please select what data you want to load:");

    String selection = input.next();

    int temp = 0;

    for(int i=0; i< header.length; i++){

        if(header[i].equals(selection)){

            temp = i;
        break;

      }
    }
```

temp will give us the index of the option specified so if it is 2 we will want to access the age property

When my console application runs I prompt them(the user) for the data that they want.
So they may enter "age" So I am lost on how I may take this "age" String and access the person object with it.
The ideal case for the program output should be: `20,30,24` going through each age and printing

I take their input so `String input = scanner.nextLine();`
Then I loop through my array of person objects to get the index of the input. Once I have this index I then want to access the property of person at the index. So like if my index was 1 I would want to access the property 'name'.

In javascript I could take the string and say `person['age']` although java's a whole different story. I have looked into java's "reflection API" although it's a heavy learning curve.

Comment: *"When my console application runs I prompt them(the user) for the data that they want"* -- please share that code as well.

Comment: @NicholasK done

Comment: So you want to search only by `age`?

Comment: exactly! @NicholasK

Answer (score 1):

> I have looked into java's "reflection API" although it's a heavy learning curve.

Well, Reflection *is* the way to go. It's widely used in many frameworks.

But perhaps a simpler solution will fit your needs. Use a `switch` to decide which attribute to return, and encapsulate this in a method of the `Person` class:

```
class Person {
  private String name, title;
  private int age;

  public loadData(String csv){
      String[] list = csv.split(",");
      name = list[0];
      title = list[1];
      age = Integer.parseInt(list[2]);
  }

  public Object attribute(String attribute) {
      switch (attribute) {
          case "name": return this.name;
          case "title": return this.title;
          case "age": return this.age;
          default: throw new RuntimeException("Invalid attribute: " + attribute);
      }
  }
}
```

Encapsulating the switch inside the method is in line with OOP principles, since it hides how attributes are stored from other objects, only exposing an interface to query them. Reflection breaks all encapsulation.

Comment: Reflection is actually the worst choice, and should be avoided as much as possible.  It’s slow because it can’t be optimized by the JIT compiler;  it’s error prone because errors can’t be detected at compile time.

Comment: This is a helpful answer although in my actual program (not the above program) I have 20 or more attributes and am trying to avoid preparing for hard coded possibilities as it isn't so efficient

Comment: It's less efficient to learn an API you yourself said has a steep learning curve... is it not?

Answer (score 0):

First thing, we should add a constructor to your `Person` class.

```
class Person {
  public Person(String name, String title, int age) {
    this.name = name;
    this.title = title;
    this.age = age;
  }
}
```

Now while you read the input you can use a `Map` as follows. Here after reading each line, we create a `Person` object and then using that person's age we make an entry in the map with key as `age` and value as `Person`.

```
Map<Integer, Person> mapOfPeople = new HashMap<>();
while (input.hasNextLine()) {
    String line[] = input.nextLine().split(",");
    Perso person = new Perso(line[1], line[0], Integer.parseInt(line[2].trim()));
    mapOfPeople.put(person.getAge(), person);
}
```

Now to fetch a particular `Person` by `age` just do

```
mapOfPeople.get(20);
```

Comment: What happens if the dataset includes > 1 person of a given age? Also, I know the OP answered only interested in search by age, but if, as the OP noted in a comment on another question, there are many attributes, it seems unlikely that the long term approach is to rely only on a single age attribute to search. Therefore, this example code will not scale.

Comment: Hmm, yeah scaling isn't the question here. I do understand the issue when 2 people have the same age, but I would redirect that question to @Matthew Fallon. What should happen in that case?

Answer (score 0):

Though in general I am not in favor of using `Map` for holding fields for an object, if the number of properties is large and could even potentially vary across CSV files (e.g., some file has the University a person attended, another does not), then using a `Map` to hold the properties might be appropriate.

In this case, one would define a simple `Person` class:

```
public class Person {
  Map<String, String> props = new HashMap<>();

  public void addProperty(String propertyName, String value) {
    // could add error checking to ensure propertyName not null/emtpy
    props.put(propertyName, value);
  }

  /**
   * returns the value of the property; may return null
  */
  public String getProperty(String propertyName) {
    return props.get(propertyName);
  }
}
```

If it is know that certain attributes/properties will always be loaded, then accessors such as `getName()` could be added:

```
public String getName() {
  return props.get("name");
}

public int getAge() {
  String age = props.get("age");
  // or throw exception if missing
  return (age != null ? Integer.parseInt(age) : -1);
}
```

Though note I would expect name to not be a single entry for most datasets, as there typically would be last name, first name, etc. Nonetheless, the pattern for a limited number of commonly expected values is the same. Also, you can adapt so that you could get integer values directly for certain well-known fields.

Then, when you parse the file, you keep the title row that has the attribute definitions. Then for each row that you subsequently read, you create a new `Person` object, and then add the properties in order.

```
List<Person> allPersons = new ArrayList<>();

while ( (line = READ_NEXT_LINE) ) {
  // NOTE: this is not a safe way to handle CSV files; should really
  //   use a CSV reader as fields could have embedded commas
  attrs[] = line.split(",");
  Person p = new Person();
  for (int i = 0; i < titleRow.length; ++i) {
    p.addProperty(titleRow[i], attrs[i]);
  }

  allPersons.add(p);
}
```

You can then get a specific `Person` by `Person myPerson = allPersons.get(index_of_person)`, and much akin to the way you would have used `Javascript`, you can do `String val = myPerson.getProperty("age")`.

If you need to search by a given attribute, you can then stream/loop over the `allPersons` and check of equivalence based upon a given property.

```
// find all people of a given age
List<Person> peopleAge20 = allPersons.stream()
            .filter(p -> p.getAge() == 20)
            .collect(Collectors.toList());
    System.out.println(peopleAge20);        

    // summary statics (average age) for all people
    IntSummaryStatistics stats = 
            allPersons.stream().mapToInt(p -> p.getAge()).summaryStatistics();
    System.out.printf("Average age: %f\n", stats.getAverage());
```

Note that this approach does break the idea of a `Javabean`, but that may or may not be an issue depending upon your requirements.